# method of including data in a url

Tags: javascript, url

URLs include data about where have you been in a website and when you re-visit, they show the exact information. For example I was in Google Maps, searched "Barcelona" and then "fly" to the Isle Of Man. If you open this url `https://www.google.com/maps/place/Barcelona/@54.2584676,-4.4790783,10z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x12a49816718e30e5:0x44b0fb3d4f47660a` you will see Barcelona in the search box (`place/Barcelona`) but the map will zoom in the Isle Of Man (`@54.2584676,-4.4790783` lon-lat I guess)?

So it shows you where I have been, not just a map and an empty search box. This happens to most websites, urls include data about photos, profiles, modules etc. I am not talking about simple anchors like (`site.com/page.html#header`). I am NOT talking about AJAX.

I want to learn more on how you can store data in a url and when you visit it, the page loads specific parts AND data.

What is the name of that method? How does it work? How do I implement it?

Answer (score 1):

One of the things I believe you're referring to is the `GET` method.

To add data to the *query string* (that's what the string is called that is usually after the question mark (`?`) and the divided by the and sign (`&`) depending on the number of attributes you want to pass to it.

One way of passing attributes to the query string is by using the `GET` method in a form for example as follows:

```
<form method="get" action="other-page.php">
    <input name="example" type="text" />
    <input name="other" type="text" />
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Once you click submit on the above form, the `name` attributes of the inputs will become the attributes of the query string and their values will be whatever has been added as value for those fields. So if you filled in *'this'* for `example` and *'that'* for `other`, then the query string would look like this:

```
domain.com/page?example=this&other=that
```

This information can then be retrieved on the other page that the form has been sent to (you will see the name of that other page under `action="other-page.php` in the `form` tag).

Assuming it's a page written in [php](/questions/tagged/php), this is how you can get the values of the attributes:

```
echo $_GET['example']; // this would output 'this'
echo $_GET['other']; // this would output 'that'
```

In your example, google for example uses the `lon` and `lat` attributes to place you on the right spot on the map. Though looking at their query string, they look like using a different method than the classic `GET` as I explained above.

The hashtag however (`#`) is there to point to specific sections of a page (assuming it's not being manipulated by some javascript code, but that's a whole different story). If you setup a link like this one:

```
<a href="section2">Click here to go to section 2</a>
```

...then further down on the page you added...

```
<a id="section2"></a>
```

...and clicked the link above, the page would jump down to section 2 for you.

Comment: OK Thanks. So to sum up, this "`GET`/query string" thing has nothing to do with AJAX. What other ways I can use to create a query string except forms? If a user clicks an image and I want to update the url without reloading the page, how can I do it? And can I use javascript to handle (deserialize?) the incomming query string?

Comment: no, by default it has nothing to do with AJAX... another way would be to use it in an `a` tag (wrapped around your image), redirecting to that string (`<a href="?example=this&other=that">...</a>`) though this will refresh the page... and here is a way you can get url parameters using js: [http://code-tricks.com/get-url-parameters-using-javascript/](http://code-tricks.com/get-url-parameters-using-javascript/)

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the history-API, espacially `history.pushState()`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries

Comment: Thanks very much. But this implies the use of HTML5. The method I describe existed before HTML5. So, what about before HTML5? What happened then?